# Many to many table with an additional id column

Tags: mysql, hibernate

In hibernate if i do the following

```
class User{
     @ManyToMany
     private List<UserRole> roles; 
}
```

it creates a separate table  `User_UserRole` where there is two column (`user_id and roles_id`)

But i want a third column in there e.g "`id`"  which uniquely identify each row and the id's are auto generated.

How do I Do this ???

Comment: autoincreament.......is not workint??

Comment: there is only two column, i need the third column first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with default behavior you cannot achieve this, but if you can create the table by yourself in the database (instead of letting hibernate doing it) and then mapping

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "User_UserRole", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID") },    inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "ROLES_ID") })
private List<UserRole> roles;
```

of course you will make the id column autoincrement also in the table definition.

Answer (score 1):

You could do that with the following implementation

```
@Entity
class User{
     @Id
     private int id;
     @OneToMany(mappedBy=role)
     private List<UserRole> roles; 
}


@Entity
@Table(name="USER_ROLE")
class UserRole{
     @Id
     private int id;   <--ID you were looking for
     @ManyToOne
     private User user; <--User ID
     @ManyToOne
     private Role role; <--Role ID
}

@Entity
class Role{
     @Id
     private int id;
     @OneToMany(mappedBy=user)
     private List<UserRole> roles; 
}
```

Trick is break ManyToMany relationship in two OneToMany pointing to the Jointable. This works !!
Also you can add another columns in the USER_ROLE table, without breaking anything